# R.string comparison

Tags: java, android

I am trying to compare a simple string from the R.string class but something is wrong.

```
if(this.b1.getText().equals(R.string.stop_track))
```

The b1 text is equals to stop_track text, why I'm getting a false result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`R.string.stop_track` is an `int` identificator of your string, not it's value. Try to use this line of code:

```
if(this.b1.getText().equals(getString(R.string.stop_track)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will accept your answer as correct as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

`R.string.stop_track` itself is just a reference, in the form of an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Error is coming because `R.string.stop_track` is return an integer, so Write below code instead of your code, it will solve your problem.

```
if(this.b1.getText().toString().equals(getResources().getString(R.string.stop_track)))
```